# How do I use custom DataAnnotations to validate more complex data types?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, architecture, data-annotations

### Introduction

Decorating properties with `[Required]` and `[MaxLength]` is simple enough and works great. It also comes with client-side validation.

Often, however, your data is more complex. Perhaps you need to check if something in a database exists or communicate with an external service to verify something. You still need validation but the standard DataAnnotations are not enough.

A good way to do this is with custom DataAnnotations. You could create your own called `[UniqueEmailAttribute]` which checks the database to see if the email input already exists.

### The problem

This presents an architectural problem. If you use a custom DataAnnotation like this, how do you support Separation of Concerns, Dependency Injection etc? In the past I've simple created a new `DbContext`, instantiated the required objects and done my validation. This is ugly and breaks my design philosophy.

*What is a great solution to validating form data while maintaining great code design?*

> I realise it seems this question has been answered before, but remember that my question is not "how can this be done?" but rather "how can this be done well?", or, "what is best practice?" This question is about maintaining cohesive solution/project structure and design. Code examples can be in C# or VB.NET. Links to MVC4 example projects are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write a custom annotation that hooks into the jquery validator

You could then use this to call a controller method via ajax to do the validation

It still feels like a bit of a hack (and probably brittle), but seems better than having logic and dependencies in your attributes